# how to write the output of a loop for in txt file in golang

Tags: go

i'm new in go, i want to know, how to write the output of loop for in txt file in golang  here my code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        if i%2 == 0 {
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("%d ", i)
        file, err := os.Create("result.txt")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal("Cannot create file", err)
        }
        defer file.Close()

        fmt.Fprintf(file, " x equal to %d", i)

    }

}
```

but i get 9 instead  of 1 3 5 7 9 
so how to fix that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are recreating the file each iteration of the loop, which is why the only value in the file is the last value you write in the loop.

Try the following

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Create("result.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot create file", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        if i%2 == 0 {
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("%d ", i)
        fmt.Fprintf(file, " x equal to %d", i)
    }
}
```